# How to make form upload multiple files?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a question about uploading multiple files? I have set the HTML to multiple="multiple" and then you can upload multiple but what I received in the email is only one file. Is there a way to make it upload multiple files not just one? Im thanking you in advance. Here is the php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

 */
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['name','email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('message')->maxLength(6000);

$pp->attachFiles(['image']);

$pp->sendEmailTo('ragnaruus3@gmail.com'); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

```js
$(function() {
  function after_form_submitted(data) {
    if (data.result == 'success') {
      $('form#reused_form').hide();
      $('#success_message').show();
      $('#error_message').hide();
    } else {
      $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

      jQuery.each(data.errors, function(key, val) {
        $('#error_message ul').append('<li>' + key + ':' + val + '</li>');
      });
      $('#success_message').hide();
      $('#error_message').show();

      //reverse the response on the button
      $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function() {
        $btn = $(this);
        label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
        if (label) {
          $btn.prop('type', 'submit');
          $btn.text(label);
          $btn.prop('orig_label', '');
        }
      });

    } //else
  }

  $('#reused_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $form = $(this);
    //show some response on the button
    $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function() {
      $btn = $(this);
      $btn.prop('type', 'button');
      $btn.prop('orig_label', $btn.text());
      $btn.text('Saadab ...');
    });


    var formdata = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'handler.php',
      data: formdata,
      success: after_form_submitted,
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="contact-area-right">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <form role="form" method="post" id="reused_form" enctype=&quot;multipart/form-data&quot;>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name"> Nimi:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required maxlength="50">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email"> Email:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required maxlength="50">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name"> Sõnum:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Sinu sõnum siia" maxlength="6000" rows="7"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name"> Lisa manusesse fail (Max 25mb):</label>
              <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image" multiple="multiple" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right" id="btnContactUs">Saada! &rarr;</button>
          </form>
          <div id="success_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
            <h3>Sinu sõnum saadeti edukalt!</h3>
          </div>
          <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
            <h3>VIGA</h3> Vabandame sinu sõnumi saatmisega tekkis viga. Palun vaadake sõnum üle. </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to deal with multiple uploads:

```php
    // the form field of type FILE in the HTML is named "upload" - yours may have other name, e.g. "image"

    // Count # of uploaded files in array
    $total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);

    // Loop through each file
    for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ )
    {
      //Get the temp file path
      $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

      //Make sure we have a file path
      if ($tmpFilePath != "")
      {
        //Setup our new file path
        $filename = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
        $size = $_FILES['upload']['size'][$i]; // might not be needed in your usecase

        $newDir = '/var/www/files/knowledge';
        if(!file_exists($newDir)) mkdir($newDir, 0777, TRUE);

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newDir.'/'.$filename))
        {
          // do whatever you need - e.g. store some info into a database
        }
      }
    }
```